# Why would a Flash/SWF populate as a white box on remote machines?

Tags: php, html, apache, flash, shockwave

I'm fighting something a little outside my normal areas of I.T. expertise.  I feel like I'm missing something that will be obvious to many of you.

My kids loaded a Club Penguin private server on one of the computers.  It's running via XAMPP on a Windows 10 box, and it works well when using a Flash browser by going to "localhost."  The challenge comes in when another player tries to access it from another machine by going to the machine's local IP address.  When browsing to the address, the index.html page loads fine.  The challenge is that the index.html calls load.swf which populates in the home page as a white box.  Right clicking in the white box will bring up a flash menu, so we know the Shockwave file is there so to speak.

Testing brought up the following.

I took another .swf file that was from one of my websites back in the Flash days.  I renamed that file to load.swf, put it in place of the Club Penguin, load.swf file, and mine populates and runs just fine.  So the index.html code seems to work fine.  That puts me back at the swf file.

One other head scratcher.  From the machine running XAMPP, as I said, it runs fine by surfing to localhost.  However, even on that machine it exhibits the same behavior if localhost is replaced with the machine's local IP. The index.html loads fine, but the swf populates as a white box.  Likewise, the same thing happens of surfing to the loopback address.

Playing with the URLs in the swf file have proved unsuccessful so far.

Thanks for any insight you're willing to offer.  If this had been a project that was billable by the hour I could take a vacation on it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Open a web console and monitor the differences in URL-requests for the resources/files. There are bound to be some.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who read my post in hopes of helping.  As so often happens, after I posted, I figured it out.  For anyone else who experiences this, I went out to our server and found an old copy of ASV 5.  It allowed me to see what I was missing with the other editors.  In the load.swf, and the local & global crumbs swf there were some instances of localhost that I couldn't find with the other editors.  Changed them to the host IP, and boom goes the dynamite.

Hope it helps someone else someday.